# What are the alignment limitations of the standard global default operator new?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, com, memory-alignment

I'm working on some older code that uses ATL's `CComBSTR` type. I'm changing it so that it will compile using Visual C++ Express Edition, which does not come with ATL. I used only a very small subset of `CComBSTR`, so doing this is fairly simple.

However, when allocating the `BSTR` memory block, I need to fill the first four bytes with a 4 byte length prefix. I'm concerned that if I use a `new char[size]` expression to allocate the memory for the string, that I will cause alignment faults due to the allocated `char` array not having the correct alignment for the four byte prefix.

Is there anything in the standard that states what alignment requirements the returned values of `new` have? All I see in C++11 are:

> 5.3.4/1 [expr.new]
>   It is implementation-defined whether over-aligned types are supported (3.11).
>
> 3.11/6 [basic.align]
>   The alignment requirement of a complete type can be queried using an alignof expression (5.3.6). Furthermore, the types char, signed char, and unsigned char shall have the weakest alignment requirement. [ Note: This enables the character types to be used as the underlying type for an aligned memory area (7.6.2).—end note ]

I find this slightly confusing -- "weakest alignment requirement" says to me "least strict constraint on alignment", but the note under this seems to indicate the standard means the opposite.

Am I safe using a `new char[sizeof(uint32_t) + 2*(length + 1)]` buffer as a `BSTR` like this?

**EDIT**: I just realized that in this specific case of `BSTR`, one needs to use SysAllocString in order to allocate the string anyway; but I'm still interested in whether or not it is okay to use `new` in this way.

Comment: It's pretty unlikely you'd run into alignment issues in practice, though the standard won't say anything about it.  If you used `malloc()`, you'd likely find that it returns blocks of memory that are 8-byte or even 16-byte aligned (because the data it returns must be sufficiently well aligned for use with any basic type); it is plausible, but not guaranteed, that `new` et al will behave similarly.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: The standard for `malloc` explicitly says (C99, 7.20.3/1) `The pointer returned if the allocation succeeds is suitably aligned so that it may be assigned to a pointer to any type of object and then used to access such an object or an array of such objects in the space allocated (until the space is explicitly deallocated).`) -- that seems like a pretty good guarantee to me.

Comment: Yes — for `malloc()`, that's good; and the 'likely 8-byte or 16-byte align[ment]' is because of that guarantee plus the normal restrictions on types for 32-bit and 64-bit systems.  But `operator new` and the `new` operator are not the same as `malloc()` and I am not sure what promises the C++ standard makes about the return values when you ask for `new char[17]`, say.  That's why these are comments, too, not an answer; I'm being too lazy to go look at the actual C++ standard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 5.3.4/1 [expr.new]
>
> It is implementation-defined whether over-aligned types are supported (3.11).

One important thing here: `over-aligned` means more aligned than any built-in type. For example, on 64 bits machine, pointers are generally 8 bytes aligned and thus on those machines over-aligned means having an alignment strictly greater than 8.

Therefore, `over-aligned` is only of concern when using vector types, such as those required for SSE or AVX instructions or some variants of C/C++ (like Open CL). In day to day programming, the types you craft from the built-in types are never over-aligned.

> **§3.11 Alignment [basic.align]**
>
> **3/** An *extended alignment* is represented by an alignment greater than `alignof(std::max_align_t)`. It is implementation-defined whether any extended alignments are supported and the contexts in which they are supported (7.6.2). A type having an extended alignment requirement is an *over-aligned* type.
>
> **9/** If a request for a specific extended alignment in a specific context is not supported by an implementation, the program is ill-formed. **Additionally, a request for runtime allocation of dynamic storage for which the requested alignment cannot be honored shall be treated as an allocation failure.**

Furthermore, it is customary for `new` to return memory aligned to `alignof(std::max_align_t)`. This is because the regular `::operator new` is only aware of the size of the object to allocate for, not of its alignment, and therefore need satisfy the strongest alignment requirements possible in the program.

On the other hand, beware of a `char` array allocated on the stack, there is no guarantee what its alignment would end up being.

Comment: Yes; on the stack I've been using `std::aligned_storage` .+1

Comment: "for which the requested alignment cannot be honored" -- what is "requested alignment"?

Comment: @BillyONeal: I must admit I am not too sure (in this context). In §17.6.3.5/6 it is said that allocators instantiated for a type with a *requested alignment* they do not support can either fail to instantiate (compile-time failure), throw upon allocation (runtime failure) or ignore it. Which is rather clear because the allocator is templated on the type and thus knows its alignment. However in the case of `::operator new(size_t)` I don't quite see what it could be other than `alignof(std::max_align_t)`.

Answer (score 7):

It is an implementation detail, but MSVC uses the operating system allocators.  HeapAlloc() for CRT allocations, CoTaskMemAlloc() for COM type wrappers like _bstr_t.  They both align by 8, both in 32-bit and 64-bit code.

You should never allocate memory for BSTRs with the *new* operator, the COM allocator must be used to ensure that they get deallocated using the proper heap.  Important in any interop scenario, which is where BSTR is used, it is a standard Automation type.  CoTaskMemAlloc/Free() is required but always use the BSTR helper functions to ensure they get properly initialized.  SysAllocString() and SysFreeString().  Use SysAllocStringLen() to deal with strings containing embedded zeros.

Answer (score 0):

You should never try to use C++ memory management functions for BSTRs - they should only be allocated using `SysAllocString()` family functions. This ensures that whoever obtains a `BSTR` can use `SysFreeString()` and other functions of the family on the obtained `BSTR`. If you violate this requirement your program will run into undefined behavior.

Comment: 1. I believe Hans' answer covered that quite well over a day ago. 2. I believe I already updated my question to this effect. 3. Not always. If passing a BSTR to a function that does not conceptually take ownership of that BSTR, it doesn't matter what allocation function one uses.

Comment: @Billy ONeal: Actually you're wrong about point 3. Even if a function doesn't take ownership of the string it can still use `SysStringLen()` which relies on proper string allocation.

Comment: `SysStringLen()` relies on the length prefix being present. It doesn't care from which heap the string was allocated.

Comment: @Billy ONeal: Strictly speaking, it relies on some implementation specific internal data that is crafted by `SysAllocString()` and the like. Trying to craft that in user code is not an example of best practices.

Comment: I suppose we can agree to disagree on that point then. The format of BSTRs is entirely allowed to not be allocated by SysAllocString -- if that were true, what the compiler does in the `BSTR()` macro would be illegal, and it isn't. This isn't an implementation detail but a well documented contractual part of COM.