# Placement-new address alignment

Tags: c++, memory-management, undefined-behavior, memory-alignment

According to https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/dtors#placement-new
the address passed into placement-new has to be properly aligned. But the example it gives seems to contradict that.

```
char memory[sizeof(Fred)];
```

This buffer is most likely **not** aligned for Fred, since it's a dumb `char[]`, so `memory` can point to pretty much anywhere. Then it does placement-new on this address.

**Is the example contradicting the alignment requirement it says in the *DANGER* footnote?**

*That leads to a related question:*

How can I create a buffer (either stack or heap) that is **aligned** for a type `T` (to use in placement-new of one or more T objects)?

By buffer I mean a `char[]` or `void*` buffer of some size, not a `T[]` because that would be object allocation which defeats the point of doing placement-new afterwards.

Thank you.

Comment: Unless a char[N] is aligned to objects of size N then yes, it contradicts the footnote. Gotta check if the standard has anything to say about this...

Comment: We have no information regarding `Fred`, `sizeof(Fred)` may be 0 or 1.

Comment: @YSC if it's not specified, you shouldn't assume anything. And `sizeof` cannot be 0 as per the Standard.

Comment: I agree, you should not assume their example is wrong. Especially when it is given with a warning saying when alignment would be a problem.

Comment: @YSC No, from the answers below, the example is wrong, when no assumption is made. You are making an assumption.

Answer (score 19):

Use the `alignas` keyword:

```
alignas(Fred) char buf[sizeof(Fred)];
::new (static_cast<void*>(buf)) Fred;
```

Or use `std::aligned_storage` if you prefer a library wrapper around this construction.

Comment: Upvoted, but why do you need a cast to `void*`? `::new (buf) Fred;` seems to work just fine, any pointer can be implicitly converted to `void*`, can't it?

Comment: Implicit casts to and from void* are only legal in C.  C++ has a stricter type system.

Comment: @vsoftco: That one may be overloaded. The form I chose cannot be overloaded. It depends on what amount of customization you want to allow; you can also say `new` instead of `::new` to consider class overloads.

Comment: @JeremiahB No, implicit casts to `void*` are OK in C++ as well. The other way around doesn't work.

Answer (score 10):

About your first question: according to the [answers to this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11214632/alignment-guarantees-of-static-char-array) yes, the example got it wrong:

> Statically allocated arrays are aligned to sizeof(element_type) bytes
>   -- for char it is 1 byte, which basically guarantees no alignment.

thus the array `char memory[sizeof(Fred)]` has no alignment guarantees for `Fred`.

The proper way of doing it is as follows (C++11):

```
alignas(Fred) char memory[sizeof(Fred)];
```

Answer (score 3):

For heap allocations just use `std::malloc` which it is guaranteed to allocate memory that is aligned for any type.

For stack allocations, if you have access to C++11, then you can use [`alignas`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignas) as in

```
alignas(T) uint8_t data[sizeof(T)];
```

If you don't have access to C++11 then you must fallback to specific compiler attributes as GCC's [`__attribute__((aligned(N)))`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3/gcc/Type-Attributes.html).

Comment: Or make a union with the char array and the alignment type.

Comment: your statement on heap allocation for "any type" is wrong. See this comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6973995/dynamic-aligned-memory-allocation-in-c11#comment23703633_6974009

Comment: @PoweredByRice: you can't have a type which natively has an alignment greater than `std::max_align_t`, your original question isn't about alignment requirements for objects that have requirement which are not related to their definition (eg SSX or AVX requirements) so `std::malloc` is safe for any type, unless you have some specific requirements that you didn't mention. Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13097268/what-are-the-alignment-limitations-of-the-standard-global-default-operator-new

Comment: `std::alignas`?  I thought `alignas` is a C++ keyword, not a member of the `std` namespace.

Comment: @TobySpeight: Indeed it's a keyword, my fault.